# Storing secrets in ASP.NET Core for deploying at a shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to store my secret keys for a non-azure environment. Actually for a shared Asp.Net Core hosting.

I have a little idea about storing in appsettings.json & have tried some online resources but no solution worked for me.